# Save Multiples times Cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, database, save, cakephp-3.0

What I want to do is to save my data multiple times. In order to do that I put this code in my Controller :

```
foreach ($tw->statuses as $t) {
            $tw->image = $t->user->profile_image_url;
            $tw->name = $t->user->name;
            $tw->screenname = $t->user->screen_name;
            $tw->message = $t->text;
            $tw->Fil_id = $FiltreId;
            $this->Twes->save($tw);
    }
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

However when the execution is done, I found only the last record saved in my database, and not the other ones. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be happening due to various things:

1. The variable `$tw->statuses` only contains ONE status.
2. The table where you store the data has a unique index that collides when the data is inserted for the second time.

Can you give more information (like the table description, or a var_dump of the named variable before iterating it) to exactly pinpoint what's happening?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. when i debug $tw it contains more than one status(at least 5). i think the problem is that using save(); the data as you said collides, because in the database i find what has been recorded is the last data.

Comment: @Sam then the problem could also be that inside the `foreach` you are mutating an instance which is `$tw` and maybe that's why the same row is being saved, therefor can you try to do the following in the first line inside the `foreach`?

`$test = clone $tw;`
`$test->image = $t->user...` and so on

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. I updated my code, and i used TableRegistry and used newEntity inside my foreach as you can see :

```
$oPeople = TableRegistry::get('Tweets');

    $oQuery = $oPeople->query();

    foreach ($tw->statuses as $t) {
            $test = array($FiltreId,$t->text,$t->user->name,$t->user->screen_name,$t->user->profile_image_url,null,null,null,null,null);
            $tw = $oPeople->newEntity($test);
            $tw->image = $t->user->profile_image_url;
            $tw->name = $t->user->name;
            $tw->screenname = $t->user->screen_name;
            $tw->message = $t->text;
            $tw->Fil_id = $FiltreId;
            $this->Twes->save($tw);
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

This way all the data is saved, and not only the last one.